# C# unsigned int default value

Tags: c#

What is the default value of unsigned int in c#?

For ex: int, its 0, i want to know for unsigned int, will unsigned int support assigning null value to it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use this to figure it out:

```
default(uint); //0
```

To assign a null value to it you need to use a `Nullable<uint>` or just `uint?`. Now if you have a `uint?` you can do the same thing to see it supports a null value.

```
default(uint?); //null
```

Answer (score 14):

It's zero, and no you can't assign null to it. You can, however, assign a null to `int?` or `uint?` - also known as `Nullable<Int32>` and `Nullable<UInt32>`.

Answer (score 3):

The default value of any struct, including unsigned int (`[mscorlib]System.UInt32`) is all-zeros, which is 0 for a uint.

You can't assign null to any struct, but you can use `Nullable<uint>` (aka `uint?`) if you want a uint that can be assigned null.